# Инка или инк?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Коренное население Перу - инков знают все. Но вот только я никак не могу понять до конца, как правильно называть одного представителя этого народа: инк или инка?
В литературе я встречала оба варианта и мне, в свое время большой поклоннице творчества Казанцева (речь о трилогии "Фаэты"), ближе форма "инка".
А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...как правильно называть одного
> представителя этого народа: инк или
> инка?

Правильно по Зализняку (Грамматический словарь русского языка) и ***инк,*** и ***инка.***

Оба слова -- **мужского рода.** Склоняются так:

**инк,** *инка, инку, инка, инком, о инке; инки, инков, инкам, инков, инками, о инках.*

**инка,** *инки, инке, инку, инкой, о инке; инки, инк (затрудн.), инкам, инк (по-моему, тоже затрудн.), инками, о инках.*

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, в русский язык первоначально пришёл вариант "инка", но в связи с редким употреблением этого слова в единственном числе, из слова "инки" позже образовался вариант единственного числа "инк". Иначе трудно найти объяснение тому, что в других языках попадается только первый вариант (inca/inka). Ведь похожие случаи бывали с другими словами, напр. слово "зонт" произошло от мнимого уменьшительного "зонтик" через оригинальное zonnedek.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/12826516/
См. книгу "Последний инка".

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка вверху на Зализняка - корректна, но... Но ведь много интереснее о гражданах Непала. 
Конституция
Гражданином Непала признаётся человек, рождённый от непальца и непалки!

Comment: очень смешно, но инк в переводе - это чернила. Чернилами называть народ как-то не очень удобно, и даже если тату весь инк разрисован, тату - тоже неудобно. Однако факты татуировки у инков были, и именно поэтому их назвали чернилами. Англичане не стали заморачиваться проблемами, как было, так и назвали, а нашим при переводе стало неприятно грустно, авось народ иностранное слово не поймет, так и сработало, не понимают до сих пор.

Comment: > рождённый от непальца и непалки  Не так: правильно: "рождённый непалкой и непальцем"